# Does the elementary knot move really preserve the orientation?

Tags: algebraic-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

[image]

So in this picture, the first diagram changed to the third diagram by the elementary knot moves, but the orientations of the first and the third are different. I wonder if in $R^3$ the moves don't preserve the orientation?

Comment: You can get from the triangle on the left to that on the right by a rotation $\in SO(3)$, which representes the pinnacle of orientation preservation. So I don't think there is a problem. Maybe you mean the fact that those triangles don't induce the same orientation on the plane they are drawn on, but an orientation on a vector space ($\Bbb R^3$ here) doesn't induce one on its subspaces (for instance the two dimensional plane that carries both triangles), so that would also be a moot point. Do you have something else in mind?

Comment: @ Olivier Bégassat, Thank you very much, that makes sense, I just focused on the subspace and forget they are in $R^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olivier Bégassat's comment is flawless, and OP agrees that it answers the question, so I am posting it as an answer. (M. Bégassat, if you prefer to post it yourself, please do, and I will delete this and upvote yours.)

> You can get from the triangle on the left to that on the right by a rotation $\in SO(3)$, which representes the pinnacle of orientation preservation. So I don't think there is a problem. Maybe you mean the fact that those triangles don't induce the same orientation on the plane they are drawn on, but an orientation on a vector space ($\Bbb R^3$ here) doesn't induce one on its subspaces (for instance the two dimensional plane that carries both triangles), so that would also be a moot point.